# Clear the previous input once the selection is selected

Tags: angularjs

How would I clear the input box once the user select from dropdown using angularjs.

every time clear the input box once the selection is made.

here is what I put together the sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/abuhamzah/jb1j3w7x/

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
      <label class="col-xs-6 control-label">Type:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
         <select name="type" ng-model="payment.type" ng-dropdown required ng-change="changeme(payment.type)" >
            <option ng-option value="Cash">Cash</option>
            <option ng-option value="Check">Check</option>
            <option ng-option value="Money Order">Money Order</option> 
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
    {{ payment.cash }}
   <div class="col-xs-12" id="cash" ng-if="payment.type == 'Cash'">
      <div >
         <label class="col-xs-6 control-label">Cash :</label>
         <div class="col-xs-6"> 
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12" id="check" ng-if="payment.type == 'Check'">
      <div >
         <label class="col-xs-6 control-label">check :</label>
         <div class="col-xs-6"> 
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12" id="money_order" ng-if="payment.type == 'Money Order'">
      <div >
         <label class="col-xs-6 control-label">money_order :</label>
         <div class="col-xs-6"> 
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>


 <div class="col-xs-12" ng-if="payment.type == 'Check' || payment.type == 'Money Order' || payment.type == 'Cash'">
      <div > 
         <div class="col-xs-6"><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="payment_input"/>{{payment.type}}</div>

    </div>          
</div>


var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


function MyCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.changeme = function() { 
      alert(payment.type);
      payment_input='';
  }
}
```

Comment: does not work, so what i want is that when the user select cash and enter some value and if the user change selection from cash to check or money order i want the input box to be clear all the time, i hope i make sense

Comment: yes, sorry for that..added answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this more easily with `$watch`, which is designed for this purpose.

In your controller:

```
$scope.$watch('payment.type', function (newVal, oldVal) {
  $scope.payment_input = 0;
  // anything else you want to do when the payment type is changed
})
```

Now whenever `payment.type` is changed, these lines will be executed.

Here are more docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

**EDIT**

**Here is a working fiddle with your code:** http://jsfiddle.net/jb1j3w7x/5/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if` for input element `container` because the following reason

> The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree
>   based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates
>   to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a
>   clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

Approach 1: (using controller)

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jb1j3w7x/2/

Approach 2: (you can update the model without controller)

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jb1j3w7x/4/

Also,

- You have missed to add $scope for updating the number field
- Number field should be updated as number. we cant update as empty
  text

Comment: i'm still not seeing what i want, its not clearing the previous selection

Comment: chk this out, i remove $scope.payment=0 http://jsfiddle.net/abuhamzah/jb1j3w7x/3/

Comment: its working in my end..input field is rest to zero whenever you change the type dropdown.

Comment: I am sorry I meant to say without using the controller is that possible to put logic on the UI?

Comment: yes try this http://jsfiddle.net/jb1j3w7x/4/ ..just update the model in ng-change="payment_input = 0"

Comment: Is there any reason you're not trying the solution I wrote? It is built into angular and much simpler.

Comment: I don't think that the need of watch method here..We can achieve the result many way and I had followed simple way..Also, Questioner wants to update the model without controller logic..

Comment: Down voter! please tell the reason!! So that I can change myself if anything I am wrong.